# Dynamically adding form elements with jQuery and Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form in which people shall be able to add the same portion of elements with a plus-button, so that something like this is produced:

```html
<div id="person-1" class="person">
    <input type="text" name="name-1" id="name-1" />
    <input type="text" name="age-1" id="age-1" />
</div>
<!-- as of here, it's JS created -->
<div id="person-2" class="person">
    <input type="text" name="name-2" id="name-2" />
    <input type="text" name="age-2" id="age-2" />
</div>
<div id="person-3" class="person">
    <input type="text" name="name-3" id="name-3" />
    <input type="text" name="age-3" id="age-3" />
</div>
```

I already managed to write jquery-code that allows me to add the same elements once again with a new id (name-1, age-1, name-2, age-2, name-3, age-3, …).

Of course, Zend_Form does not know about **name-2** and **name-3**, so it just drops them when the form contains an error and is displayed again. Neither can I access the value of **name-2** with `$form->getValue('name-2')`. I have to go over raw `$this->getRequest()->getPost()`.

Is there a better method I can use to combine Zend_Form and javascript-based added form elements (of same type like an hardcoded element).

**Caveat**: In the real problem, it’s `select` and not `input`. Found out this could make a difference (with `->setIsArray(true)`), but using `select` would blow up the example code.

Comment: Have you considered using the notation `name="names[]"`? Wouldn't that help you?

Comment: Yeah, Zend does not seem to allow `[]` in the attribute name. I can call the element `second[]` within my application, but it will still be given `name="second"` in HTML. :/ And when I use `setIsArray(true)`, it will make my `select`-field multiselect (I do not have text, but select in real problem).

Comment: Seems like I can [introduce a `preValidation()` method](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/) to my form which checks for new elements and adds them to the Zend_Form hierarchy.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691378/allow-a-user-to-add-fields-to-a-form-created-with-zend-framework/6691659#6691659

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create a subform container inside your main form and add an X amount of subforms to that container.
For example:

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    private $_numPersons = 1;

    public function setNumPersons($numPersons)
    {
        $this->_numPersons = (int) $numPersons;
    }


    public function init()
    {
        $container = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $this->addSubForm($container, 'persons');

        for($index = 0; $index < $this->_numPersons; $index++) {
            $personForm = new My_PersonForm();
            $container->addSubForm($personForm, $index+1);
        }
    }
}
```

When rendered, the input fields will have names like `persons[1][name]`. Note the `$index+1`, Zend_Form does not allow a form to be named '0'.

Ofcourse, you should only use this method if the amount of person subforms is limited.

Another strategy would be to override the `isValid` method and use a single `My_PersonForm` form to validate all the person data.

Sidenote; the above code will only work when you define the numPersons as part of the options set, when creating the form instance. E.g.;

`$form = new My_Form(array('numPersons' => 10));`

Comment: Does not really seem to work :/ Always one level is missing. Now it’s: `array(2) { ["persons"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(2) "ab" ["age"]=> string(0) "" } ["submit"]=> string(23) "Save" }` When I reduce complexity and add only one subform, this subform is directly copied into the root of the $_POST data (without the subform-name being an array index), like this: `array(3) { ["name"]=> string(2) "ab" ["age"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(23) "Save" }`

Comment: Quite hard to help you without seeing the exact code you've written, but at least make sure that the Person form is an instance of `Zend_Form_SubForm`. If you're using the `ViewScript` renderer to render your form, you might want to prepend the `PrepareElements` decorator to the form decorator stack. Also note that you add the `PersonForm` to the `$container` subform and not the main form.

Comment: Yeah, it was not an instance of `Zend_Form_SubForm`. Thanks :)